# Graph API calls & access_tokens

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

the situation: 
I am using open graph requests like "https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXX/posts?access_token=XXXXXXX" to display the posts of a facebook page (that I own - but that shouldn't matter, the page is public) on my website. I generated the token by using the open graph explorer

the problem: the access token expires.

I read about using the sdk for refreshing the tokens or creating a freaking app (which, after creating one,  seems to be a wide topic - and much to complicated for such simple needs).

My Simple Question is: is there a simple way for me to get permanent access to a >>public<< facebook page.

I hope so, I don't have the time to dig into a sdk (I know this sounds bad but it's only a side-project for a friend)

Answer (score 0):

You should use an "Extended Page Token", which is valid forever. How to generate that Token is explained in the following links:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

The basic concept:

- Get a User Token with the `manage_pages` permission.
- Extend the User Token.
- Get an Extended Page Token by using the `/me/accounts` endpoint with the Extended User Token - or just `/page-id?fields=access_token` to only get the Token for a specific Page.

Answer (score 0):

Access token generated through graph api has a limited validity.Once you submit your app to facebook and it gets approved then you can generate access token with never expiry validity .But again user keeps the right to cancel the access token anytime from his app setting . There is no way you can get a permanent access token .